# Why is my React app not opening up in the browser

Tags: reactjs, browser

I was working on a small app in React but suddenly when I ran 'npm start ' command. The source compiled but the browser just kept on loading and my app wasn't showing up.

I tried restarting my laptop multiple times and I also tried replacing start in package.json .. by "start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start"/

Comment: is there any console errors? if yes, pls post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://hashnode.com/post/having-problems-with-your-react-app-not-loading-and-throwing-the-page-unresponsive-message-heres-a-fix-ckmli1ims044ro4s14xgobdhc

Best solution, basically I was stuck in an infinite loop.
So, got rid of it ... you can refer the link for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your console? Maybe there is some error message there. Maybe your configuration is wrong, your components, routes, or imports are wrong. You can use a debugger to check your app and see where the error is.
This [link](https://daveceddia.com/react-app-not-working-quick-debugging-tips/) could you help you